Blazor Entity Framework, .NET 8, DbContext scoped to component lifetime
I am using .NET 8 Blazor (server side) to access a Cosmos database using EF Core 8.
In the generated program.cs, there is the standard call to
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>.....

Given this razor code:
@inject ApplicatioDbContext myContext
..
@code {
  private myMethod() 
  {
      myContext.Add(...)  <-- myContext is null
  }
}

I'm unable to find in the documentation anything (up-to-date) that shows how to initialize MyContext.
I'm under the impression that somewhere there should be some code to actually retrieve the service and set MyContext such that I can then add/retrieve data.
Does anyone have an idea for the missing functionality?
As a 10-point bonus to this question, I would like to replace the builder.Services.AddDbContext with builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory so a solution that would work using this would also be great.

Search "Blazor DbContext" and you will find this MS docs article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0 - which I believe answers your question.  There are also many answers already [some of mine!] on SO - search "Blazor DbContext".

The fix for this was to change the rendermode to InteractiveServer.  Any other mode and the injected context remained null.
I added to the head element in app.razor
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />

and to the body element in the same file
<Routes @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />


Make sure to configure the program.cs first.
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseCosmos("your-cosmos-endpoint", "your-cosmos-key", "your-database-name"));

next make sure to define the context
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TblTest> tblTest { get; set; }
}

next you can invoke it
private async Task MyMethod()
    {
        using (var myContext = DbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
           var newEntity = new TblTest { Name = "New Entity" };
           myContext.AddAsync(newEntity);
           await myContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

The context add is used to add following data into the database.

Thanks, as my app is a .net 8 blazor app - the out of the box code has what you have in the first two code sections.   I assume the async MyMethod is in the razor view.  The issue I have is that when I inject the context into the view, it is always null.

When I say 'it is null'  I am referring in the example to the DbContextFactory variable.
